# Launch jobs in LSF one batch after the other

Tags: redis, spring-batch, hpc, lsf

I have say 10,000 orders. Each order has multiple(10 to 5,000) order items. I have a pipeline in Spring-batch to do some processing on those data. I have one job(tasklet style) written to process orders and another job written to process individual order items.

Each ***OrderJob*** do something(i.e copy order table details to another database) and then notifies their *#OrderNumber* and *#OrderItemNumber* to a Redis channel queue. A listener is listing to that redis channel and launches the ***OrderItemJob*** job in LSF HPC Cluster for each order item to do their processing.

The issue I am facing here is one order may trigger 10,000 of OrderItemJobs and if I run all the orders in one go, it will produces 10000*10000 jobs which cannot handled by LSF queue as my LSF queue allows to hold jobs on pending state only 10000 jobs maximum. (I am using a job group to control #running jobs, but when it reaches 10000 jobs, no one cannot submit any new jobs to queue - which matters!)

Therefore, I want to run orders batch by batch(say 10 orders per batch). But I want to launch the next batch only if the previous batch has launched all the jobs **including OrderItemJobs** and completed. **My question is how can I know if all the jobs are completed and then automatically launch the next batch?** LSF returns an email/log once a single job is finished. **but how do I know all the jobs that are within the batch is finished?**

Comment: Why did you separate the job that processes orders from the one that processes order items? IMO this is the root cause of your problem because now you have to to find a way to orcherstrate all those jobs. Is combining order processing with its items in one job an option for you? Because if that's the case, you just have to run jobs in sequence or even in parallel.

Comment: The reason to separate job is OrderItemJobs are computationally expensive, therefore I like to run those jobs in parallel in the cluster. Say I remove the redis channel and then when I finish OrderJob, still I need to launch many OrderItemJobs that is belongs to that order. So, those jobs should be run on LSF cluster(I cannot run on a single machine). Still I will have the same issue, how do I know all the jobs are executed in cluster then run the next Order jobs

Comment: Your decomposition of the problem makes it hard to scale. Your tasks are dependent on each other (first `OrderJob` then `OrderItemJob`). If you manage to decompose the problem in independent tasks (like for example a job for the order **and** its items, even if those jobs are CPU intensive, that's not the issue), you can parallelise the work load among your cluster. In Spring Batch terms, a CPU intensive task is a good candidate for [remote chunking](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/scalability.html#remoteChunking) where Redis could be the communication middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Are you suggesting to A) combine OrderJob and OrderItemJob into a single job or B) to separate all the jobs to individual jobs? If B) is the answer, what I can do is, I can push the #order and #orderItem into Redis and my listener should launch the jobs to LSF. But I do not know how to control it. because whenever listener find an accession, it will launch a job to LSF

Comment: I don't know what business logic your jobs are doing but I'm suggesting option A. I think processing an order with its items in one job is a cohesive design. Moreover, this will make jobs independent from each others, hence easily parallelisable on your cluster. Finally, this would not require orchestration using a redis queue, listeners, notifications, etc.